# Find the value of the constant c such that $\sum_{n=2}^\infty(1+c)^{-n} = 2$

Tags: sequences-and-series, proof-verification

> Find the value of the constant c such that $$\sum_{n=2}^\infty(1+c)^{-n} = 2 $$

For this question,I'm not sure if I'm doing it right. If I am doing it right, I'm not sure how to get further. Here is what I have so far. Can anyone please help me out?

Comparing the series to the conventional form $a + a r + a r^2 + \cdots = a/(1-r)$, we have

$$r = 1+c \qquad\text{and}\qquad a = (1+c)^{-2} \qquad\text{and}\qquad 2 = \frac{a}{1-r}$$
So ...
$$\begin{align}
2 &= \frac{(1+c)^{-2}}{1-(1+c)} \\
2 &= \frac{(1+c)^{-2}}{-c} \\
-2c &= (1+c)^{-2} \\
-2c &= \frac{1}{(1+c)^2} \\
-2c(1+c)^2 &= 1 \\
-2c(1+2c+c^2) &= 1
\end{align}$$

Comment: The series is $(1+c)^{-2} + (1+c)^{-3} + \dots$

Answer (score 2):

When the series converges,

$$\sum_{n=2}^\infty(1+c)^{-n}=\frac{(1+c)^{-2}}{1-(1+c)^{-1}}=\frac1{(1+c)\,c}=2.$$

Solve $$c^2+c-\frac12=0.$$

After solving, check the convergence condition, $|1+c|>1$.

Comment: Where did $(1+c)^-1$ come from?

Comment: @dg123: this is a geometric series.

Comment: the r is 1+c though, so shouldn't the denominator just be $1-(1+c)$?

Comment: If it converges, doesn't it converge to $\frac{a}{1-r}$ for a geometric series?

Comment: @dg123: exactly. Observe again.

Comment: So the r would just be (1+c) wouldn't it?

Comment: @dg123: obviously not.

Comment: I am confused. Why is it to the power of -1 if there is no -1 in the r? Isn't it just supposed to be what I wrote above if it converges to $\frac{a}{1-r}$?

Comment: @dg123: don't ignore my previous comment.

Comment: I am still confused. Could you explain to me why it's $(1+c)^-1$?

Comment: @dg123: See Unit's comment to your question.

Comment: But how does that relate to what r is? Can you explain it to me?

Comment: @dg123: review the definition of $r$.

Comment: When the sum is from 0 to infinity, the series converges to 1 over 1 minus r and the absolute value of r is less than one

Comment: I still don't really see where the power to the  -1 comes from

Comment: Oh wait , it can be seen as 1+c to the power of n times -1

Comment: so the r is $(1+c)^-1$

Answer (score 0):

HINT: you must solve the equation $$\frac{1}{c(1+c)}=2$$ for $c$
this comes from $$\sum_{i=2}^n(1+c)^{-i}=\frac{(c+1)^{-n-1} \left((c+1)^n-c-1\right)}{c}$$

Comment: Where did the $\frac{1}{c(1+c)}$ come from?

Comment: this is the sum of your infinite geometric series, should i add this step?

Comment: But if it converges, doesn't it converge to $\frac{a}{1-r}$?

Comment: what denotes $a$ here? compute the limit in the formula above for $n$ tends to infinity

Comment: $a = (1+c)^-2$ isn't it?